# Reference on rigorous formulation of mirror symmetry conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, mirror-symmetry

I am looking for a mathematically rigorous formulation of mirror symmetry conjecture in the flavour of the original paper by Candelas, de la Ossa, Green and Parkes

https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(91)90292-6

In section 7 of the paper,

https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9308083.pdf

mirror symmetry conjecture is also formulated, see formula 7.8 in this paper. I am wondering are there any references which state mirror symmetry conjecture in the same way, but in a mathematically rigorously way (i.e. in a way which mathematicians are happy with and could accept without any doubt)?

I think I need to apologise to authors of these two papers (perhaps the physicists community) for asking such a question.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.claymath.org/publications/monographs/mirror-symmetry
would be the place to start. It has contributions by both mathematicians and physicists.

Answer (score 1):

Cox and Katz's book Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry is a natural place to start if you're interested in a historically informed mathematical approach to mirror symmetry for Calabi-Yau threefolds.